# How can I include Beta versions in `npm outdated`?

Tags: node.js, npm

Running `npm outdated` gives the following results:

```
Package               Current      Wanted  Latest
bootstrap          4.0.0-beta  4.0.0-beta   3.3.7
```

How can I hide this? The version is correct as I've specified, but npm doesn't seem to detect it. `yarn outdated` correctly marks this as not outdated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. `Alpha`, `Beta`, `Release candidate`, means that this version is not ready for production, and can be used only for testing. So the latest *production ready* version is 3.3.7

Comment: It seems strange for npm to have an opinion on what versions I should to use in my own project. IMO, if I specify I want to use version X, npm shouldn't tell me its wrong; `outdated` should just tell me if its the most recent version or not (which is not what it currently does)

Comment: `npm` just shows the latest _stable_ and latest _unstable_ versions. If you decide to use unstable version, `npm` informs you about that.

Comment: Fair enough. It still seems strange to me that `outdated` shoud have an opinion on me using Beta versions of software; that should be users choice, and `outdated` should simply *tell you what is outdated*, IMO.